# Limit of $\frac{1}{M} \int_1^M M^{\frac{1}{x}} \textrm{d} x$ when $M \to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

**The exercise**

Find the limit of
$$
\frac{1}{M} \int_1^M M^{\frac{1}{x}} \textrm{d} x
$$
when $M \to +\infty$.

**My try**

I tried a change-of-variable but as the lower bound of the integral is $1$ and not $0$, it wasn't successful. I showed that the limit, if it exists, is $\geq 1$. We also have: $\frac{1}{M} \int_1^M M^{\frac{1}{x}} \textrm{d} x = \int_1^M M^{\frac{1}{x}-1} \textrm{d} x$ and in the integral, $\frac{1}{x}-1 < 0$.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you give some Background about the problem to lry to look for an adequate tool?

Comment: Sorry, it was given as such in an contest @TitoEliatron
I think one has to use mainly real analysis techniques ^^'

Comment: Have you tried [First mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals)? Just an idea Not sure if it works

Comment: The thing is that $M$ is also in the integral...
Something that could help could be the fact that $M^{\frac{1}{M}} \to 1$ when $M \to +\infty$
Maybe breaking the integral in two parts in a Cesaro way is interesting

Comment: My Hint works if the integral goes from any $a>1$ to $M$. But nor $a=1$ fails....

Comment: $1$  is problematic?

Comment: Yes, because MVT gives $c_M\in[1,M]$ such that the integral equals $(M-1)M^{1/c_M}$. But as $M\to\infty$, $c_M$ may go to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacLaurin Expansion of $m^y$ is
$$m^y=1+y \log m+O\left(y^2\right)$$
Therefore
$$m^{1/x}=1+\frac{\log m}{x}+O\left(1/x^2\right)\tag{1}$$
Integrate
$$\int_1^m \left(\frac{\log m}{x}+1\right) \, dx=m+\log ^2 m-1\tag{2}$$
Thus
$$\underset{m\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{\int_1^m m^{1/x} \, dx}{m}=\underset{m\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{m+\log ^2 m-1}{m}=\underset{m\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(1+\frac{\log ^2 m}{m}-\frac{1}{m}\right)=1$$

---

**Edit**

$(1)$

$$\int_1^m \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx=1-\frac{1}{m}$$
$(2)$ becomes
$$\int_1^m \left[\left(\frac{\log m}{x}+1\right) +O\left(1/x^2\right)\right]\, dx\le m+\log ^2 m-1 +1-\frac{1}{m}=m+\log ^2 m-\frac{1}{m}$$
Thus to a greater extent $(2)$ holds

Comment: Nice answer! Can I ask you why you ignored $\int_{1}^{M} O(1/x^2)dx$? (or maybe it is just $0$, so the question becomes: why is it $0$?).

Comment: Basically, he uses a theorem telling: when $f\geq0$ and $\int_a^{+\infty}f = +\infty$ and $g \underset{+\infty}{\sim} f$, one has $\int_a^x f \underset{x \to +\infty}{\sim} \int_a^x g$. Am I right @Raffaele?

Comment: @Contestosis Yes

Comment: @SabakuSouSou I edited my answer to add the reason why I ignored the big O part

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof you could use, which is more like the standard analysis proof.

Observe that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} M^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$$
Hence there exists $K(\epsilon)$ such that $$\forall x > K : \left | M^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1 \right | < \epsilon$$
Also, note that: $$\sup_{1\leq x \leq K} \left | M^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1 \right | = c < \infty$$
for some constant $c(K)$.

Now, combining the above, we have that:
\begin{align}
 0 &\leq \frac{1}{M} \left | \int_1^M M^{\frac{1}{x}}dx -  \int_1^M 1 dx \right| \\ &\leq \frac{1}{M} \int_1^M \left | M^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1 \right| dx \\
&= \frac{1}{M} \int_1^K \left | M^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1 \right| dx + \frac{1}{M} \int_K^M \left | M^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1 \right| dx \\
&\leq \frac{c(K-1)}{M} + \frac{\epsilon (M- K)}{M} \\
&\leq \frac{c(K-1)}{M} + \epsilon \\
&\to 0 \text { as } M\to \infty
\end{align}

Hence, we can conclude that:
$$\frac{1}{M} \int_1^M M^{\frac{1}{x}}dx= \frac{1}{M}\int_1^M 1 dx = 1$$

Comment: You can assume that $M>K$ because $M\to\infty$?

Comment: $K= K(M, \epsilon)$, in fact. How can we know that $K = o_{M \to +\infty}(M)$? Same for $c(K) = c(M, \epsilon)$.

Comment: Apparently, the proof needs to be modified to work. I am not sure I see the right direction.